# Winter and my tools

Tags: power-tools

It is getting cold here in Wisconsin, winter is coming. I have always taken in my battery tools. Because most people should know that lithium and freezing temps, do not mix very well. But what about my other corded tools? Do I need to bring those inside. keep in mind, at this time I don't own my own place, only 17, so I am out in the shed, and there is no heat and open building (we have one cow on the other side). I am wondering if the freezing temp will screw up any bearing or, anything. Thoughts?

Quick edit: We no longer have the cow.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue. By necessity all sorts of corded tools are left out through winters of many severities in unheated and/or uninsulated buildings (garages, garden sheds, barns and other outbuildings) without any apparent harm coming to them. They may not work well *while* frozen, but after thawing they should be back to normal.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks for the comment. It is good to know because I was told not to leave them out in the shed. But as long as it doesn't screw them up I would rather leave them out, for space reasons.

Comment: Related: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3226/how-do-i-know-when-it-is-too-cold-to-work-outside

Comment: @Matt Super useful information from that page. Helps me with the answer to my question.

Comment: This will vary from tool to tool. Electronic circuits (including electromagnets in motors) generally perform more efficiently in the cold, because reducing the temperature will reduce resistance in a conductor. Printed circuit boards however do not do well under repeated expansion and contraction (cold/hot/cold/hot), which will add to the wear and tear on the soldered joints. Electrochemical processes such as those happening in a battery, and viscosity of fluids will change with extreme colds. User manuals generally cover safe operating temperatures. This should include storage too.

Answer (score 4):

Your corded tool will be fine. For storage make sure the tools are kept dry and shielded from dust and dirt (from caring for the cow perhaps). If you use the tools when they are cold it is best to let them warm up a bit before use instead of plug in and cut. Take precaution bringing cold tools into warm spaces as condensation can become an issue.